# Bottom Overflow Error On A Page With NavigationRail

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fix bottom overflow issue. It was easy for me to fix it before NavigationRail. Now I tried some solutions but couldn't make it work. I tried to wrap some widgets with singlechildscrollview but my screen goes all white when i do that. If i wrap the NavigationRail with singlechildscrollview or flexible, it is not working either. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDesktopBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyDesktopBody> createState() => _MyDesktopBodyState();
}

class _MyDesktopBodyState extends State<MyDesktopBody> {
  NavigationRailLabelType labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Row(
        children: [
          NavigationRail(
            groupAlignment: 1,
            leading: SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: Image.asset("assets/bdklogo.png")),
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink.shade100,
            onDestinationSelected: (value) {
              setState(
                () {
                  _selectedIndex = value;
                },
              );
            },
            destinations: const [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: Text("Anasayfa")),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.text_snippet_sharp),
                  label: Text("Instagram Eğitimi")),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mark_as_unread_outlined),
                  label: Text("İletişim")),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box), label: Text("Hesabım")),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box), label: Text("Giriş Yap")),
            ],
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
          ),
          _desktoppages[_selectedIndex],
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

final List<Widget> _desktoppages = [
  const DesktopHomePage(),
  const DesktopInstagramEducationPage(),
  const DesktopContactPage(),
  const DesktopProfilePage(),
  DesktopLoginPage(
    emailController: TextEditingController(),
    passwordController: TextEditingController(),
    confirmPasswordController: TextEditingController(),
  ),
];

class DesktopHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DesktopHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "A'DAN Z'YE INSTAGRAM EĞİTİMİ",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.brown.shade400,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                              offset: const Offset(3, 3),
                              blurRadius: 3,
                            ),
                          ],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Merhaba! Ben Ebru! İşim markalar için strateji oluşturmak ve markaların dijital dünyada kimliklerini bulmalarına yardımcı olmak... Sizler için gerçekten işinize yarayacağını düşündüğüm, bildiklerimi asla saklamadan sunduğum, size sadece Instagram’ı öğretmekten öte motivasyon da olacağına inandığım, dijital dünyanın şifrelerini çözmenize yardımcı olacağını bildiğim bir eğitim hazırladım.",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                          "/Users/tfy/Downloads/UDEMYFLUTTER/bdkakademi/assets/ebru.png")
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),

            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text("Daha Fazla Bilgi Alın"),
            ),
            Text("EĞER SİZ DE"),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Text(
                      "Sürekli başkalarının sayfaları ile kendi sayfanızı kıyaslıyorsanız,",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
                  Text(
                      "Ne yapmam gerektiğini bir türlü bulamıyorum diyorsanız,",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
                  Text(
                      "Ne yapmam gerektiğini bilsem de nasıl yapılacağını asla anlayamıyorum diyorsanız,",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
                  Text(
                      "Bu algoritmanın benden ne istediğini bir türlü anlayamadım diyorsanız,",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
                  Text(
                      "Instagram sayfamı artık kendim yönetmek istiyorum, başkalarına boş yere para dökmek istemiyorum diyorsanız bu eğitimde yerinizi almalısınız.",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Text("BEN KİMİM?"),
            const Text("Ebru Yılmaz'ı yakından tanıyın."),
            Text(
                "2008 Uluslararası İlişkiler Lisans eğitimimi 2010 yılında da aynı anabilim dalında yüksek lisans eğitimimi tamamladıktan sonra anladım ki akademik kariyer bana göre değil. Benim en iyi yaptığım şey, araştırmak ve yazmaktı. Bu hayallerimin peşinden giderken 2011 yılının ocak ayında bir ajansta içerik yazarı oldum. Şans ve çalışma azmim neticesinde 8 ay sonra ayrılan editör ve aynı zamanda genel yayın yönetmenimizin yerine ben geçtim. O günden beri de basılı ve dijital birçok dergide editörlük, dijital içerik yazarlığı ve dijital editörlük yaptım. Bundan 6 sene önce de dijitaldeki değişimi keşfederek sosyal medya ve özellikle Instagram konusunda kendimi eğitmeye başladım. Şimdiye kadar 25.000 TL’nin üzerinde eğitim için harcama yaptım. Sadece eğitimlerin bir işe yaramadığını, pratiğe dökmedikçe her bilginin kaderinin suda eriyen sabundan farksız olduğunu gördüm. Araştırdım ve hep daha çok araştırdım. En çok kendimle yarıştım.",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
            const Text("Bugüne kadar;"),
            Text(
                "100 + hesap için çalışma yaptım. 120 + kişiye Instagram hakkında sunum yaptım. 20.000 + kişiye ücretsiz Instagram yönetimi bilgisi verdim. 5.000 + kişiye mail ile ulaşarak iş geliştirmelerine katkı sağladım. 10.000 + soruya cevap vererek akıllarında kalan soru işaretlerine çözümler bulmalarına yardımcı oldum.",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text("Daha Fazla Bilgi Alın"),
            ),

            // BURAYA TANITIM VİDEOSU GELECEK

            const Text("BEN HAYATA NASIL BAKIYORUM?"),
            const Text("İstiyorum ki;"),
            const Text(
                "Kendi sayfanızı kendiniz yönetin ve sürekli başkasına bu iş için para vermek zorunda kalmayın. Bu alanda kendinizi yetersiz hissetmeyin. Farklı bakış açıları yakalayın ve hayatınıza yenilikler katın. İstiyorum ki kendinizi yalnız hissetmeyin, herkesin aynı duygu durumundan geçtiğini ve sizin hislerinizi paylaştığını bilin. Satış yapmak artık sizin derdiniz olmaktan çıksın, bu hayatın güzel anlarına daha kolay odaklanın…"),
            Text("Peki, bunun için ne yaptım?",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
            Text(
                "Gerçekten işinize yarayacağını düşündüğüm, Bildiklerimi asla saklamadan sunduğum, Size sadece Instagram’ı öğretmekten öte motivasyon da olacağına inandığım, Dijital dünyanın şifrelerini çözmenize yardımcı olacağını bildiğim bir eğitim hazırladım.",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```